# Possible to keep same lines in same color in different plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have a figure A consists of 10 lines : 1 to 10, colored by default settings of matplotlib.

Now I want to plot lines 1-5 in figure B and lines 6-10 in figure C, but keep the colors of the lines consistent. I mean in figure B, colors of line 1-5 are the same with line 1-5 in figure A; and in figure C, colors of line 6-10 are the same with lines 6-10 in figure A.

Is there a way doing this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you link your plots by assigning a label (useful if you have a legend anyway) then you can lookup the previous colour.

Original problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np


f, axs = plt.subplots(3)

lines = [np.random.rand(10,1) for a in range(10)]

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    axs[0].plot(line)

for i, line in enumerate(lines[:5]):
    axs[1].plot(line)

for i, line in enumerate(lines[5:]):
    axs[2].plot(line)

axs[0].set_title("All Lines")
axs[1].set_title("First Five")
axs[2].set_title("Last Five")
f.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("No Linking.png")
```

[image: No Linking of colours]

Then add some labels instead:

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(3)

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    label = "Line {}".format(i)
    axs[0].plot(line, label=label)

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if i < 5:
        ax = axs[1]
    else:
        ax = axs[2]

    label = "Line {}".format(i)
    # here we look up what colour was used in the first subplot.
    colour = [l for l in axs[0].lines if l._label == label][0]._color
    ax.plot(line, label=label, color=colour)



axs[0].set_title("All Lines")
axs[1].set_title("First Five")
axs[2].set_title("Last Five")
f.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("With Linking.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

For the lines 6-10 just plot 5 blank lines before plotting the actual lines that you want to. 1-5 will already have the default colors that match the 1-10 scheme.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0]) # line 1
plt.plot([0]) # line 2
plt.plot([0]) # line 3
plt.plot([0]) # line 4
plt.plot([0]) # line 5
plt.plot([1,2,3,4]) # line 6
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```